# CKEditor 5 copy selected content from one editor to another

Tags: ckeditor5

I have two editors on the screen, one read-only.  What I want to do is allow the user to select content from the read-only editor and paste it into the current position of the other by clicking a button. (the logic may manipulate the text which is one reason I don't want to use the system's clipboard.)

So far I have the function that is able to paste the text like as follows.  (I am using the Angular wrapper which explains the presence of the **CKEditorComponent** reference.

```
  doPaste(pasteEvent: PasteEvent, editorComponent: CKEditorComponent) {
    const editor = editorComponent.editorInstance;
    editor.model.change(writer => {
      writer.insertText(pasteEvent.text, editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition() );
    });
}
```

What I can't find from the documentation is how to extract the selected text.  What I have so far is:

```
  clickPasteSelectedPlain(editorComponent: CKEditorComponent) {
    const editor = editorComponent.editorInstance;
    const selection = editor.model.document.selection;
    console.log('clickPasteAll selection', selection);
    console.log('clickPasteAll selectedcontent', editor.model.document.getSelectedContent);
  }
```

The **selection** appears to change depending on what is selected in the editor's view.  The **getSelectedContent** function is undefined.  How do I get the content?

Comment: I think you could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51540657/1485219) to extract selected text.

Comment: @oleq I saw that answer but I discounted it because there is no getSelection() function in editor.  At least not in the current version.

Answer (score 4):

With a bit of poking around I figured out how to do this.  I'll document it here on the chance that it will help someone down the road avoid the process of discovery that I went through.

On the source document I have a **ckeditor** element like this:

```
  <div *ngIf="document">
    <ckeditor #ckEditor
              [editor]="Editor" [config]="ckconfig" [disabled]="true"
              [(ngModel)]="document.text"></ckeditor>
    <button mat-flat-button (click)="clickPasteSelectedPlain(ckEditor)">Paste Selected Text Plain</button>
  </div>
```

In the component the function called on the **click** event is like this:

```
  @Output() paste = new EventEmitter<PasteEvent>();
     ...
  clickPasteSelectedPlain(editorComponent: CKEditorComponent) {
    const editor = editorComponent.editorInstance;
    this.paste.emit({
      content: editor.model.getSelectedContent(editor.model.document.selection),
      obj: this.document,
      quote: false
    });
  }
```

The **PasteEvent** is defined as an exported **interface** which I will omit here to save space.   The **content** key will refer to a **[DocumentFragment](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_documentfragment.html)**.

Note that I am passing the **[CKEditorComponent](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html)** as a parameter.  You could also access it via an Angular **@ViewChild** declaration but note that my **ckeditor** is inside an ***ngIf** structure.  I think that works well in Angular 6 but in the past I have had difficulty with **@ViewChild** references when the target was conditionally in the DOM.  This method always works but use whatever method you want.

The event fired by the **emit** is processed with a method that looks like this:

```
  doPaste(pasteEvent: PasteEvent, editorComponent: CKEditorComponent) {
    const editor = editorComponent.editorInstance;
    editor.model.insertContent(pasteEvent.content);
  }
```

Because the content is a **DocumentFragment** the paste operation will include all formatting and text attributes contained in the selected source. But that's all there is to it.